# JPG Images as Fallback fom RTMP Live Streaam

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

I would like to offer a few Live broadcast to users who don't support any of the available Streaming protocols as auto refreshing JPG's.

I got the idea to use ffmpeg (or mjpg_stramer) to extract two frames per second from the RTMP Live Stream base64 ecndoe it and load them by JavaScript at half second interval, but with 5-50 concurrent streams this is a hard job for the Server.

What would be the best way to get from multiple RTMP Live Streams two (or more) images per second as Base64 encoded JPG?

Comment: If your client supports RTMP Live Stream, why not use ffmpeg to decode video? What is the incentive for base64 encoding? IIUC, even with HTTP tunneling RTMP works fine with binary stream.

Comment: @AlexCohn this would be the Fallback in case the client don't support RTMP (over Flash), HLS, MPEG-DASH, MS Smooth, HDS. As example Firefox on Android and Opera (wo Flash) can see the live stream this way.